# View In GridView

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar

I have a FrameLayout and inside it I have a `GridView`. Then I need to add a progress bar after the grid view at the bottom after `GridView` like loading, but the progress bar is coming ontop of `GridView`. Below is my code.

I am using `TabHost` which contains tab widget for tabs(3) and `FrameLayout` for `GridView` as below:

```
<

    FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/EmptyFonesLayout" >
                    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:verticalSpacing="4dp" android:horizontalSpacing="4dp" android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                        android:textFilterEnabled="true" android:background="#00ffff"/>

                   <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linlaProgressBar"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="#00FFFF"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                            <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/gridview" -->


                 <ProgressBar
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

                 <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/emptyfonetext"
                            android:text="Loading"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                </RelativeLayout>    -->
               </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyfonetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
        android:text="Loading"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

GridView on top, progress bar on bottom with the loading text on right.

[image: result]

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the answer..according to  this progressbar is on top of gridview..i want it below gridview..for example if u scroll u will get gridview attached to progressbar not ontop of it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what do you expect ... Anyway, if you scroll the gridview, the "loading bar" will always be visible.

Comment: yes ..i get the loading bar..but it comes ontop of gridview..like thegridview is in background..i need it to be like in google play..

Comment: oh got it, you want this ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923034/endless-gridview

Comment: I tried that..its coming same as above.(progressbar ontop of gridview):(

Comment: 2 solutions :

- custom component extending the GridView
- use a GridView, ScrollListener and deal with visibility of loading view (on bottom)